# Managing folder locations when swapping domains

Tags: directory

I have recently been working an application that will soon need to be moved from one server to another. (Testing environment to live environment). The problem I am having is how can I make it so when I move folders, it will still work without need needing to change directories.

Example -

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/arcade/layouts/_header.php'; ?>
```

Here I include a layout file called '_header.php', the problem I will have when I move the test environment to the live is that we will need have the folder '/arcade' so this will be looking for a folder that doesn't exist. I could use ../ or ./ but then I couldn't be able to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].

My initial thought was to have a _config.php and in it have global variables such as

```
$root = "/arcade";
```

Then when I move from the test to the live I just have to change 1 value from "/arcade" to "" and possibly the directory to the config file.

Just looking for some insight for managing folders and files across domains

Answer (score 0):

Having a configuration file is desirable anyway. Anything that is a parameter of the application (locations, access parameters etc, feature toggles, other flags etc.) should be defined there.

What is even better if you have a local configuration as well. In the configuration you can check if a local configuration exists (say `config.local.php`) and include it if it does at the end. This way you can have a minimal, possibly unversioned, environment specific override for settings that you need.

Comment: So is the approach I want to do ideal? To have the root directory in a config file and just modify it when I move from dev to live?

Comment: Rather have the live configuration in the config file and have an override for your dev env. Or even better: make the dev env as similar to the live as possible. Have a look at Vagrant: it helps creating an isolated environment in form of a virtual machine that can resemble your production so you have less 'works on my machine' type errors ;)

Comment: Yeah, I do try to do that as much as possible, the problem is with the dev environment we have multiple projects and each project has it's own folder, hence the "/arcade", when we move it to live it becomes the root directory of the website

Comment: I though so. However there's no reason why can't you have the same sub folder on live as well. Helps with scaling as well. Just imagine if you realise that your server could server multiple projects. As a general rule it's good to try to make your application as self-contained as possible so you get less conflicts with other systems.

Comment: But then wouldn't that cause an issue with there always being "/arcade" and nothing in the main root directory?

Comment: No, you just need to configure your web server accordingly. In most cases it's called the `DocumentRoot` or something similar. Also you might want to look into virtual hosts so you can serve multiple sites on the same server, each from a separate document root. But probably this is a bit off-topic for the question :)